# Fortran issue 0 + 0 not equal to 0

Tags: fortran

I decied to post here since I'm facing a very weird trouble with my fortran90 code.
Indeed, I declared double precision variables such that :

```
double precision, dimension(-1:20,-1:20) :: a,b,c
```

Then I initialize all variables to zero,

```
a(:,:) = 0.d0
b(:,:) = 0.d0
c(:,:) = 0.d0
```

And finally I do my computations,

```
a(1:17,2:18) = a(1:17,2:18) + b(1:17,2:18) + 0.5d0*c(1:17,2:18)
```

I checked each variable and they are all equal to zero before this computations but then I obtain,

```
abs(maxval(a(1:17,2)) - minval(a(1:17,2))) = 4.336808689942018E-019
```

This makes no sense but I have no idea where the problem comes from, could someone help me out on this ?

Regards

P.S : I'm using ifort with the following options : "-O3 -xHost -vec-report0 -implicitnone -warn truncated_source -warn argument_checking -warn unused -warn declarations -warn alignments -warn ignore_loc -warn usage -check nobounds -ftz"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate

Comment: If you could convert this into a copy/paste compilable example which exhibits the problem, that would be useful.  But I can't replicate using an inferred program.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your snippet on MS Visual Studio 2005 (Intel Fortran 11.0.3452.2005) and got 0.000000000000000E+000.  Same results on GNU Fortran 4.9.0.

Not sure if it makes a difference in your case, but may I suggest you to use DABS instead of ABS, though.

Fausto

Comment: Always best to use the generic intrinsic functions and then let the compiler decide how to handle the operations.

Comment: Agree with Joel, the generic `abs` is better style.

Comment: I think that that's a matter of personal policy/taste, but I _never_ let the compiler to decide whatever is better for the program statements I write.  It's sometimes a good idea, also: if I use a double-precision intrinsic function and get an error, that's an indication that I'm screwing up somewhere, and that my code needs some mending.

Comment: That is no free decision of the compiler in regards what is better! The generic resolution of the intrinsics follows the rules of the language as defined in the standard. I argue that the error catching argument is dubious, inexact assignments can be mostly caught by compiler warnings and using the generic names is regarded as better style not only by me but also by authorities, such as the great style guide by Clerman and Spector.